# Trying to figure out relation between classes but getting 1119 error

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, class

This past week I've done some AS3 class research and wrote some code but everytime I reach the point that I need something from another class I keep getting different errors >_<.

now I started from scratch to understand whats going on but even now I can't get it right.please somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

my document clas:

```
package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip;


public class main extends MovieClip {


    public function main() {
        var m23:m22 = new m22;
        addChild(m23);
        m23.x=100;
        m23.y=100;
        var k:keyz = new keyz;
        addChild(k);
        k.x=300;
        k.y=300;
    }
}

}
```

my other class:

```
package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

public class keyz extends MovieClip {

    public function keyz() {
                addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,ret);

    }
    private function ret(event:MouseEvent):void {
        main.m23.x+=10;

    }
}
}
```

problem line is"main.m23.x+=10;"

thanks you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can access the object in document class using root reference provided the object is public. Change your document class to

```
package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip;


public class main extends MovieClip {
    public var m23:m22;

    public function main() {
        m23 = new m22;
        addChild(m23);
        m23.x=100;
        m23.y=100;
        var k:keyz = new keyz;
        addChild(k);
        k.x=300;
        k.y=300;
    }
}

}
```

And your keyz class should be,

```
package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

public class keyz extends MovieClip {

    public function keyz() {
                addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,ret);

    }
    private function ret(event:MouseEvent):void {
        (root as MovieClip).m23.x+=10;

    }
}
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: so basically I can't access the class itself and should try the instance added on the stage ^_^ now I'm getting what's going on.

Comment: First you need to understand the difference between document class and a normal class in Flash. If you want to access public properties of the document class, you can access it as I mentioned above from anywhere. For other classes you need to create instance of the class like var classA:ClassA = new ClassA. And you can access the public properties using the instance variable classA.property. Hope you understand.

Comment: I wonder what if the objects already are on the stage and have instance names?

I tried some ways and keep getting "1119: Access of possibly undefined property m22 through a reference with static type flash.display:DisplayObject." thingy. is there a simple and stable way to solve this null problem?

I had the problem of stage going null after played the main timeline and go back to the same frame that have been working with  (root as MovieClip) till now.